# onDateSet never gets called, overriding buttons in datepickerdialogs

Tags: android, dialog, datepicker

I would like to override the buttons of a datepickerdialog

```
            case START_DATE_DIALOG_ID:
            DatePickerDialog datePicker = new DatePickerDialog(this, startDateSetListener, startYear, startMonth, startDay);
            datePicker.setTitle("Välj startdatum");

            datePicker.setButton(DatePickerDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Välj", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
                {
                }
            });
            datePicker.setButton(DatePickerDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "Avbryt", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
                {
                }
            });
            return datePicker;
```

Partly because I want to do some things if the dialog is canceled and partly because I want the buttons to always have Swedish titles.

My problem is that onDateSet never gets called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write your own dialog that uses a `DatePicker` widget. Those buttons are not meant to be replaced.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Is there any way of getting the current values from the datepicker dialog?

Comment: @notBanana: Call `getDatePicker()`... if you are on Honeycomb. Otherwise, there is no documented and supported way to get the "current values" other than when the user accepts the dialog. Again, if you want behavior other than what `DatePickerDialog` offers, write your own dialog that hosts a `DatePicker`.